# How to source a file in Tox

Tags: tox

How do you configure Tox to source a file before it runs your test command?

I tried the obvious:

```
commands = source /path/to/my/setup.bash; ./mytestcommand
```

But Tox just reports the `ERROR: InvocationError: could not find executable 'source'`

I know Tox has a `setenv` parameter, but I want to use my `setup.bash` and not have to copy and paste its contents into my `tox.ini`.

Answer (score 6):

`tox` uses `exec` system call to run commands, not shell; and of course `exec` doesn't know how to run `source`. You need to explicitly run the command with `bash`, and you need to whitelist `bash` to avoid warnings from `tox`. That is, your `tox.ini` should be somewhat like this:

```
[testenv]
commands =
    bash -c 'source /path/to/my/setup.bash; ./mytestcommand'
whitelist_externals =
    bash
```